# weblogic : disabling default basic authentication at application level

Tags: weblogic

How can I perform this in

enforce-valid-basic-auth-credentials - false - enforce-valid-basic-auth-credentials

in weblogic.xml of my application ?
I want to disable the default weblogic behavior of basic authentication.
 I dont want to do in config.xml or WLST script.
We are using weblogic 12c.

Thanks.

Comment: I don't think there are other options.  see -http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E15051_01/wls/docs103/upgrade/compat.html  It states, "The enforce-valid-basic-auth-credentials flag effects the entire domain. "

Comment: Did you find any solution at application level?

Comment: could you tell me the solution ?

Comment: Got the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you need to take a look at the official documentation: https://docs.oracle.com/en/middleware/fusion-middleware/weblogic-server/12.2.1.4/scprg/thin_client.html#GUID-88A9B41E-F61B-467B-B0D1-FA486E3FA855

WebLogic Server supports three types of authentication for Web browsers: BASIC, FORM, and CLIENT-CERT.

Hope that helps.